# javascript variable to external php and back

Tags: javascript, php

I need to pass value from javascript file (javascript.php) to php file (php.php), and get it back.

file javascript.php

```
<script>
var name = 'catalin';
$.post('php.php', {jsvar: name});
</script>
```

file php.php

```
$phpvar = $_POST['jsvar'];
```

How do I get variable's value back on the file javascript.php ?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

Comment: get your suitable answer from below and check that as right answer in left !

Answer (score 0):

if you r doing this with ajax then just echo the php value and get it with return value in jquery

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(e){
  var name = 'catalin';
  $.post('php.php', {jsvar: name},function(returnedValue){
 alert(returnedValue);
  });
 })
 </script>
```

in php do this

```
  $phpvar = $_POST['jsvar'];
   echo  $phpvar ;
```

you can see the result in alert.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: {"var":"value"},
  success: function(data) {
   // do something
  }
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback function as below:

file javascript.php

```
 <script>
    var name = 'catalin';
       $.post('php.php', {jsvar: name},function(data,status,xhr){
    alert(data);
    });
    </script>
```

file php.php

```
$phpvar = $_POST['jsvar'];
echo $phpvar;
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is nothing new but find the complete code. I haven't tested it. Please be aware there might be a minor typo.

javascript.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="test_request()">Test Request</button>

    <script>
    function test_request() {
        $.post("php.php", {jsvar: name}, function(data_from_php) {
            console.log(data_from_php);
        });
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

php.php

```
<?php
    $phpvar = $_POST['jsvar'];
    echo  'Hello' . $phpvar;
```

What's happening is `jQuery` is posting some value to the `HTTP` server (aka a `POST` request) and the anonymous `function(data_from_php)` is waiting for the server to respond with some data. As soon as the data arrives the function is triggered.

You can verify it from the `Chrome's` debugger window (or `Firefox` etc). For example, in Chrome just press `Ctrl+Shift+I` to open the developers tools. Click on the `Network` tab and click on `XHR` and notice when the request is made. You will be able to see what is happening under the hood and how it is working.